Amplification of recorded audio in flutter app using FFMPEG not working correctly
In my app I need to record audio and send it to server, server then sends the file to a hardware using mqtt and then file gets played on the hardware. I am using flutter to build app and using record 5.0.5 package for audio recording and for amplification ffmpeg_kit_flutter 6.0.3 package to do the amplification.
The issue is it doesnt seems like there is much change in amplitude, I used different values for amplification factor but audio remains same.
Here is the code for amplification
Future<String>? amplifyAudio(
      String inputPath, String outputPath) async {

    // Build FFmpeg command to amplify audio
    outputPath = await modifyOutputPath(inputPath)!;
    String audioFilter = 'volume=${amplificationFactor}dB'; 
    //-c:a aac
    String command = '-i $inputPath -af $audioFilter $outputPath';

    // Execute FFmpeg command
    await FFmpegKit.executeAsync(command).then((session) async {
      debugPrint("After executeAsync session ${session.toString()}");
      debugPrint(
          "After executeAsync returncode ${await session.getReturnCode()}");
      debugPrint("After executeAsync command ${session.getCommand()}");
      log("After executeAsync alllogs ${await session.getAllLogs()}");
      log("After executeAsync alllogstring ${await session.getAllLogsAsString()}");
      log("After executeAsync failStackTrace ${await session.getFailStackTrace()}");
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      debugPrint("After executeAsync error ${error.toString()}");
    });

    return outputPath;
  }


This are the logs when above method gets executed.
FFMpeg command -> `-i /data/user/0/com.orgname.flutter.appname/app_flutter/1716209206469.aac -af volume=10.0dB /storage/emulated/0/Download/1716209213238_amplified.aac`

> Logs
> After executeAsync alllogstring ffmpeg version n6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
> built with Android (7155654, based on r399163b1) clang version 11.0.5 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 87f1315dfbea7c137aa2e6d362dbb457e388158d)
> configuration: --cross-prefix=aarch64-linux-android- --sysroot=/Users/sue/Library/Android/sdk/ndk/22.1.7171670/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/Users/sue/Projects/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=aarch64 --cpu=armv8-a --target-os=android --enable-neon --enable-asm --enable-inline-asm --ar=aarch64-linux-android-ar --cc=aarch64-linux-android24-clang --cxx=aarch64-linux-android24-clang++ --ranlib=aarch64-linux-android-ranlib --strip=aarch64-linux-android-strip --nm=aarch64-linux-android-nm --extra-libs='-L/Users/sue/Projects/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/prebuilt/android-arm64/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --disable-autodetect --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --disable-sdl2 --disable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
> libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
> libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
> libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
> libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
> libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
> libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
> libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/com.orgname.flutter.appname/app_flutter/1716209206469.aac':
> Metadata:
> major_brand     : mp42
> minor_version   : 0
> compatible_brands: isommp42
> creation_time   : 2024-05-20T12:46:52.000000Z
> com.android.version: 12
> Duration: 00:00:04.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 131 kb/s
> Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
> Metadata:
> creation_time   : 2024-05-20T12:46:52.000000Z
> handler_name    : SoundHandle
> vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
> Stream mapping:
> Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
> Press [q] to stop, [?] for help

Note - I am also playing the audio after recording and before amplification in app, and also saving in download. to make sure audio file is correct.
Amplified file also gets saved but there is almost no difference.
I have also searched/googled/ and also done chatgpt to resolve issue. but nothing worked.

Note the difference between the wiki and your command line (e.g. double quotes missing - may or may not be relevant). Try using a format other than AAC (e.g. WAV) to confirm it isn't the compression re-normalising the output.
